How can I setup my IDE to look like this?
I recently learned Java and installed an IDE so that I can write my first program. I want to change the color theme and the font of the IDE to something else. I really like the way that this code snippet from ChatGPT looks like. How can I change the theme and font in my IDE so that it looks like this? I am using IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains.
A screenshot of the code snippet here

Right click on to your project and select
Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Apperance . In here , you can select theme whatever you want or modify zoom selection
For the font,
you can search in Settings and modify your font settings according to work area.

Font Settings

However , quick search in your IDE like these kind of issues would be enough to solve . Kindly reminder if you face with these types of issues another time

Yes, that helps, thank you!
